# SQL Running Total Reset on Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following table:

**Transaction History Table**

```
TransactionHistoryId    ProductCode Type    Quantity    PurchasePrice   CurrentPrice
1                       Product1    B       10          3.00            2.00
2                       Product1    B       5           7.00            2.00
3                       Product1    S       -7          7.00            2.00
4                       Product1    S       -8          3.00            3.00
5                       Product1    B       4           10.00           10.00
6                       Product1    B       5           12.00           12.00
8                       Product2    B       8           20.00           20.00
```

I would like to acheive the following table:

```
TransactionHistoryId    ProductCode Type    Quantity    PurchasePrice   QtyRunning  PriceRunning
1                       Product1    B       10          3.00            10          30.00
2                       Product1    B       5           7.00            15          65.00
3                       Product1    S       -7          7.00            8           65.00
4                       Product1    S       -8          3.00            0           0.00
5                       Product1    B       4           10.00           4           40.00
6                       Product1    B       5           12.00           9           100.00
8                       Product2    B       8           20.00           8           160.00
```

**Create Table SQL**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TransactionHistory') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TransactionHistory
create table #TransactionHistory
(TransactionHistoryId int, 
ProductCode varchar(10),
Type char(1),
Quantity smallint,
PurchasePrice decimal(18,2),
CurrentPrice decimal(18,2)
)
insert into #TransactionHistory
values
(1,'Product1','B',10,3.00,2.00),
(2,'Product1','B',5,7.00,2.00),
(3,'Product1','S',-7,7.00,2.00),
(4,'Product1','S',-8,3.00,3.00),
(5,'Product1','B',4,10.00,10.00),
(6,'Product1','B',5,12.00,12.00),
(8,'Product2','B',8,20.00,20.00)
```

**Rules**

1. PriceRunningTotal resets when the quantity running total is 0
2. PriceRunningTotal sums up only Type = 'B' (buys), when Type = 'S' (sold) keep the previous purchase price running total
3. Notice there is a Product 2 so it should have it's own running count independent of Product 1

**Purpose**

A query to ultimately find out the following:

```
Product     Quantity       AdjustedPurchasePrice
Product1    9              $11.11
Product2    8              $20
```

I used the following SQL Server 2012 query to get the result, but I feel it could be done much better:

**Query**

```
SELECT *,   
    PriceRunningTotalFinal = 
    SUM(CASE 
    WHEN QuantityRunningTotal = 0 THEN -1 * PriceRunningTotal
    WHEN Quantity < 0 THEN 0 ELSE PurchasePrice * Quantity END) OVER 
    (
        PARTITION BY ProductCode
        ORDER BY TransactionHistoryId ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
    )   
FROM (

SELECT TransactionHistoryId, ProductCode, Type,  Quantity, PurchasePrice,  
  QuantityRunningTotal = SUM(Quantity) OVER 
  (
    PARTITION BY ProductCode
    ORDER BY TransactionHistoryId ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
  ),  
  PriceRunningTotal = SUM(CASE WHEN Quantity < 0 THEN 0 ELSE PurchasePrice * Quantity END) OVER 
  (
    PARTITION BY ProductCode
    ORDER BY TransactionHistoryId ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
  )       
  FROM TransactionHistory
) AS Results1
ORDER BY ProductCode;
```

**Problem**

Ideally I would of liked to use the QuantityRunningTotal within another query but I can't nest windowed functions.

Anyone know of a more efficient way to achieve this result?

Comment: I don't understand how you have 65 as PriceRunning in the third row. Can you please explain?

Comment: @TheEsisia Yes because the sum of the QtyRunning is not zero, and it's not of type 'B' (meaning it's sold) then we just keep the last total up until that point. Only when there is a 0 in the QtyRunning that you will get a reset happening

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm.  I think something like this:

```
select th.*,
       sum(case when type = 'B' then Quantity * PurchasePrice
                else 0
           end) over (partition by grp, ProductCode order by TransactionHistoryId
                     ) as PriceRunningTotal
from (select th.*,
             sum(case when running_quantity = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by ProductCode order by TransactionHistoryId) as grp
      from (select th.*,
                   sum(quantity) over (partition by ProductCode order by TransactionHistoryId
                                      ) as running_quantity
            from TransactionHistory th
           ) th;
```

I'm not sure if this is the same logic as your query.  For this query:

1. The innermost subquery calculates the running quantity.
2. The middle subquery calculates a group based on the number of times the running quantity has been 0.
3. The outermost query then calculates the running price.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I ran the query I like the group idea, the running total seems correct but the price running total doesn't reset after TransactionHistoryID 5 you might need to scroll my table to see the full table